# Object distorting when further from player

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh, raycasting

I have a mesh following where the player is looking using a raycast. The further way from the player I look, the more the mesh distorts for some reason.

The mesh has a parent object with a constant scale of (1, 1, 1). This is used to rotate and move the mesh.

The code that moves and rotates the parent object is:

```
parentObj.transform.position = hit.point + offset;
parentObj.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(hit.normal + rotOffset);
```

[image: Looking a few meters away]
[image: Looking at the player]

I expect the mesh to remain unaffected as the scale of the mesh object and its parent object are unchanged.

Comment: Did I miss something - why do you need to rotate the object in the first place?

Comment: What happens if you take the default Unity Cube? And what happens if you move the tree gamebject to the root of the hierarchy after moving/rotating?

Comment: Moving it to the root of the hierarchy fixes it. I assume other parent objects are affecting it. Is there any way to prevent this or should I just keep it at the root?

Comment: If any of its parent (or grandparent etc.) objects are distorted, it too will be distorted.

Comment: Ah I assumed it was only the parent object that had an affect. Well at least I know better now. Thank you